# I have a problem on my Django learning. It seams path problems

Tags: path

I follow the book tangowighdjango4. I have app named 'core'. Inside it, I have templates/core and templates/registration. core and registration are the same level. base.html locates in core folder while registration_form locates in registration. When I extends {% extends 'core/base.html' and run server, it displays .....
`TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register/ base.html Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/ Django Version: 4.2.7 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:     base.html`

I have tried various settings.py
here is my register.html
`
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title_block %}
Register
{% endblock %}
`
.......